# Send info from View to Controller

Tags: php, cakephp, view, controller

I am working for the first time in cakephp for a project I am developing. In a view I have an array that I want to be able to use a controller function in it.

The array I have the info in is this one

```
 $linkedinInfo
```

And then in the view I was using a form to send the array from the view to the controller

```
       $this->Form->create('LinkedinData', array('controller'=>'Users','type' => 'post', 'action' => 'add'));
       $this->Form->input('User', $linkedinInfo);
       $this->Form->end('submit');
```

Add being add being a function in the Users controller that was not developed by me. The function being

```
       public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
          $this->User->create();
          if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
           } else {
          $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try   again.'));
         }}
```

I am getting the error "Array to string conversion" in this, I am not very familiar with working in CakePHP but I don't see why I get this since the Cookboek uses everything like me
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

---

Edit: LinkedinInfo is an array that I obtain through the Linkedin API and then I posteriorly edit it. Here a sample of the structure just for the recomendations part

```
[linkedin_recomendations] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => test1
                [relationship] => education
                [text] => Hello world
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => test2
                [relationship] => colleague
                [text] => Derp
            )

    )
```

What I am trying to do is to send this information to the UsersController where it will create an user with it in a Mongodb database

Comment: your whole form is pretty screwed up. the controller key is invalid in your create() without `url => array()`. besides, its lowercase `users`. Your input field should be `Modelname.field_name` and only contain a single value (unless its some dropdown or multiple field).

Comment: Are you sure? Because I don't see examples with url==>"array". Regarding the input field, my array is a multidimensional array, so does that mean I will have to put every field one by one?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? 1) what does the **content** of `$linkedInInfod` look like? 2) Where does `$linkedInInfod` come from? Does it need to be showed inside the form first, or do you want to insert it in the database without additional user-interaction? Please add the information to your question via the [edit] link

Comment: @user697110 yes, if the array contains multiple fields, you'll have to add multiple inputs to the form, just as you would normally create a form, e.g. Separate inputs for 'name' and 'email'

Comment: Yes, I am sure about that. You can only use the action key here directly.

Answer (score 0):

The data you are trying to submit is not formatted correctly for the save.

Please check the Book to ensure that you format your data correctly.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html